20amp Breaker Tripping on Startup of a 10amp Motor
I have an old Delta planer with a 10amp 220v 2 hp motor according to the plate on it. It has a NEMA 6-15p plug. I had it running on a 30amp circuit breaker. I moved it a 20amp breaker and it trips it on startup. I did the wiring over 20 years ago so I don't remember why I put in on a 30amp breaker. Does a 10amp 220v motor really need a 30amp breaker or could the 20amp breaker be failing? It does have a lot of mass to spin up to speed on startup. I use the same 20amp breaker for a 220v planer and 200v table saw without issue. I believe they have 2 or 3 hp motors.
Additional Information
I switched the planer to the 20amp circuit. The 30amp circuit has 12 gauge wire, which I know isn't correct. I have a 5hp bandsaw on an another dedicated 30amp circuit with 10 gauge wire. When I set it up, it tripped the breaker until I got a new/refurbished one. They don't make the breakers any more.
The planer is at least 30 years old, but only has an hour or two of use over that time.
Additional Information 2
The cord was installed by Delta, the manufacturer.
I started a second project installing a new plug on the 30amp circuit I had been using for the planer. I changed the wire to 10 gauge to support a 5hp bandsaw. When I tried turning it on, it tripped the breaker. I moved the wires to the 30amp breaker I had been using and it worked fine. It's the breaker I recently bought. Both the one that tripped and one that worked are the same type and I'm pretty sure the same brand.
Given that a new 30amp breaker fixed the tripping problem, I going to see if I can get a new 20amp breaker. I'm still curious about what breaker to use with a NEMA 6-15 plug.

Might be the planer or the breaker.  Some breakers do have a faster trip function for start up amps.  It might also be the planer has bearings going or something else, causing greater start up amps.  Did you just switch the 30 amp breaker to 20 amp breaker?  Or did you switch the planer's circuit to a 20 amp breaker with 12 gauge wire.  10 gauge wire on the 20 amp breaker might be enough.

30 years old is not the best for the lubrication of the bearings unless redone/replaced.  Dried out grease/oil might be enough to cause start up amps to be too high.

I'm not answering your specific question, but just mentioning that if you add a soft start module, you will reduce the peak starting amps and make it feasible to use the 20A breaker with your 12 ga wire.

Is the cord factory installed? What is the HP rating of the motor?

NEMA 6-15 gets a 15A breaker if it's the only receptacle or outlet on the circuit. You can install a 6-20 and plug a 6-15 into it. That's what I'm doing with my air compressor.

Motor load circuits are treated differently by the National Electrical Code because of the startup current required by the motor.
Motor branch circuit short circuit protection is sized based on the nameplate HP of the motor and the type of protection you are using.
These circuits should not have any other loads on them since they are allowed to have a higher rating of protection than general circuits.
A 2 HP single phase 230 volt motor is rated for 12 amps of current according to Table 430.248 of the National Electrical Code. This would actually only require #14 gauge wire, the minimum size for power and lighting circuits, so #12 is plenty large enough.
Also, according to the National Electrical Code Article 430. "Table 430.52(C)(1) Maximum Rating or Setting of Motor Branch-Circuit Short-Circuit and Ground-Fault Protective Devices" you are allowed to use an inverse time breaker that is sized 250% of the rating of the motor.
12 amps times 2.5 = 30 amps.
So, your 30 amp breaker and #12 gauge wire is the proper size for this circuit but not for non-motor load circuits with #12 gauge wire.
Good luck with your project!

You need a breaker with different trip curve.
Do not install oversized breaker - it will "work", but is unsafe for the circuit.
Regular breakers have magnetic trip at X times the current. In europe where I reside, that is a "B" type breaker that trips at 3-5 times the current. And of course thermally after 1h of maximum current.
To run a large motor with large startup current you will need an C-type breaker - those have trip current of 5-10 times the nominal value.
This will allow you to start the machine, while keeping your wiring adequatelly protected. Any competent store should carry breakers with different characteristics - just ask for one to "run large motors" and do not accept them giving you 30A breaker when your wiring is sized for 20A. Ask sternly for 20A breaker with C-type curve (quick google says the naming is the same in US, but do not take my word for it). The breaker pops right in to your panel, no changes necessary.
Example: I have table saw that will not start on 16A B-type breaker - most of the time breaker will trip when starting. The breaker was replaced with 16A C-type, and no more trips whatsoever. The breaker will still properly trip via thermal overload if I run more than 16A for extended period of time, preventing the wires (insulation) from melting.

North American panelboard-style breakers don't really come in different trip curves the way IEC-spec DIN-rail breakers do

Yeah, we handle that by splitting the breaker's duties. Overload protection is moved to the motor/load itself (not least it is savvy to actual motor temperature, rather than trying to guess it from afar)... and short-circuit protection isn't greatly affected by oversizing the breaker somewhat.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica Unless the load is hard-wired, upsizing the breaker risks the wire insulation melting - it is why we have breakers in the first place - to prevent people connecting loads that overheat the wiring in wall. What can be done, given the breakers for the OP panel are not available, is to install a miniature panel/distribution box in the room with tools and use modern 20A breaker with higher trip curve. Then feeder wire can use 30A breaker for bolt faults but will be protected from overload from load side.

@Thomas That's how Europe rolls.  ThreePhaseEel and I are talking about North American practice. The thing I described is used either with hardwired loads or receptacles identified for use with a particular appliance.  Overload protection at a distant breaker will never be as good as on the motor where the motor's temperature is known.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica As far as I am aware, US functions on the same laws of physics as europe. Breakers exist to protect wiring, not the tool.

NFPA writes the rules, I just know them.   On motor loads, wire overload protection is provided by the overload on the motor.  The corner case of "a limited short which draws more than wire capacity but less than upsized breaker capacity" did not occur often enough to justify downsizing the breaker and creating trip problems.  In North America we use not only physics but also accident data.  That works for us because the whole country has been building to the same codebook for 100 years.
